# MinStack LeetCode - implementing pop()

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

For [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/) LC problem, we're supposed to implement a stack that supports pop() (and other methods) in constant time. For pop(), the [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/solution/) is just

```
class MinStack {
    stack = [];

    pop() {
        this.stack.pop();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this works. How does `this.stack.pop()` call the native `pop()` method instead of calling the MinStack implementation of `pop()` (which would result in a loop)?

*Disclaimer: I'm a self taught engineer who studied on my own well enough to get into FAANG - but there's still a lot I don't know. Please be nice :)*

Comment: Which language is this? Please tag

Answer (score 1):

- If you call `this.pop()` inside `pop()`, it will result in an infinite recursion.
- `this.stack.pop()` will call the `pop()` function for the array, not the `pop()` function defined in `class MinStack` (there is no *"native"* pop function). The object for which you call `object.function()` decides the function definition that is actually evoked. So this will not be infinitely recursive.